# Remove some array object comparing with another array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, ecmascript-6

I have two dynamic array. One is Array of objects and another one is array of some string.

First Array is :

```
const initialColumns = [
{content: "Registered Name", id: "name"},
{ content: "Application No", id: "application" },
{ content: "Form Name", id: "form" },
{ content: "Registered Email", id: "email" },
{ content: "Registered Mobile", id: "mobile" },
{ content: "Payment Status", id: "payment" },

{ content: "State", id: "State"},
{ content: "City", id: "City" },
{ content: "Village", id: "Village" },
{ content: "Skype", id: "Skype" },
{ content: "Lead Stage", id: "Lead Stage" },
{ content: "Lead Type", id: "Lead Type" }];
```

Second Array is :

```
const columns = ["State", "City", "Village"]
```

Now I would like to remove some object from the first array. That object should be removed which id doesn't exist in the second array. But the objects with id email, name, application, form, mobile, payment should not be removed.

Basically I would like to remove all item which id dosen't exist in the second array. But the objects with id email, name, application, form, mobile, payment should not be removed.

Final array should be like this :

```
    const initialColumns = [
{content: "Registered Name", id: "name"},
{ content: "Application No", id: "application" },
{ content: "Form Name", id: "form" },
{ content: "Registered Email", id: "email" },
{ content: "Registered Mobile", id: "mobile" },
{ content: "Payment Status", id: "payment" },

{ content: "State", id: "State"},
{ content: "City", id: "City" },
{ content: "Village", id: "Village" },
```

Comment: what will be the output you want ? after removing some specific id what will be the output of first array ? write your first how that should be like ?

Comment: @RahulMohanty, Tthe objects with id email, name, application, form, mobile, payment should not be removed.   Question is beeing updated , please look at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    const initialColumns = [
    {content: "Registered Name", id: "name"},
    { content: "Application No", id: "application" },
    { content: "Form Name", id: "form" },
    { content: "Registered Email", id: "email" },
    { content: "Registered Mobile", id: "mobile" },
    { content: "Payment Status", id: "payment" },
    { content: "State", id: "State"},
    { content: "City", id: "City" },
    { content: "Village", id: "Village" },
    { content: "Skype", id: "Skype" },
    { content: "Lead Stage", id: "Lead Stage" },
    { content: "Lead Type", id: "Lead Type" }];
    
    const columns = ["State", "City", "Village"]
    const final=[]
    for(let i of initialColumns){
        if(columns.includes(i.content) || columns.includes(i.id)){
            if(i.content==i.id){
                final.push(i)
            }
            else{
                pass
            }
        }
        else if(i.content!=i.id){
            final.push(i)
        }
        else{
            {}
        }
    }
    
    console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

`slice()` to take part of the array and not to modify the existing

`filter()` for filtering out values

`includes()` to check if array contains specific element

```
const filtered = initialColumns.slice(6).filter(c=>columns.includes(c.id))
```

now when you have filtered values you can combine with first 6 values

```
const finalResult = initialColumns.slice(0,6).concat(filtered);
```

Docs: [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [fiter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: sorry to say that Array is dynamic. Objects with id email, name, application, form, mobile, payment should not be removed. These object index could be changed ... so I have to work with id

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
initialColumns.filter((column, idx) => idx < 6 || columns.includes(column.id))
```

Comment: sorry to say that Array is dynamic. Objects with id email, name, application, form, mobile, payment should not be removed. These object index could be changed ... so I have to work with id